# Добавление строки в файл .txt

Tags: c#

На C#, с использованием форм виндоус, пишу приложение, которое позволяет ввести некоторую строку string, после чего ее, по идее, должно записывать в файл в документах.

На деле файл перезаписывается, тогда как мне нужно, чтобы строка добавлялась В КОНЕЦ файла.

```
string Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) +"\\My Games\\FG";
string fileName = Path + "\\log.txt";               
if (File.Exists(fileName)) 
{  
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))) 
  {
    sw.WriteLine(text);
    sw.Close();
  }
} 
else 
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName,     FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))) 
   {
     sw.WriteLine("None");
     sw.Close();
   }

}
```

Comment: У конструктора `FileStream` есть параметр `FileMode.Append`. У конструктора `StreamWriter` есть параметр `bool append`. Удачи в их исследовании!

Comment: не используйте `+ "\\something"` для сборки путей. Для этого есть метод `Path.Combine(path1, path2)`, который корректно обрабатывает наличие/отсутствие слешей. А для вашего случая - есть перегрузка с 3-мя параметрами path.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Зачем так сложно?

```
File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
```

Если в `text` нету перевода строки, не забудьте добавить `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: надо еще перенос строки в конце добавить

Comment: @PashaPash: Угу. Или `AppendAllLines`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This text is always added, making the file longer over time 
// if it is not deleted. 
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
{
    sw.WriteLine("This");
    sw.WriteLine("is Extra");
    sw.WriteLine("Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `FileMode.Open` на `FileMode.Append`.

Или используйте `File.AppendText(path)` вместо ручного создания `StreamWriter`.